# I am getting an error trying to use the end function to find the end of a string

Tags: rust

```rust
extern crate regex;

use regex::Regex;

fn main() {
    /* Input for testing*/
    let text = "definitions:\n\ta = point(3,3); \n\td = point(9,4);\n\tx = circle(a,1);\n\ty = square(d,2)\n
operations:\n\tprint(x);\n\tprint(y);\n\tintercts(x,y)\nend.";

  let def_regex = Regex::new(r"^definitions").unwrap();
  let ws_regex = Regex::new(r"^ ").unwrap();

    while data.chars().count() > 0 {
        if ws_regex.is_match(&data)  {
            data = data.chars().skip(1).collect();
            continue;
        }
        if def_regex.is_match(&data) {
            let pos = def_regex.find(&data).unwrap();
            data = data.chars().skip(pos.end()).collect();
            println!("DEFINITIONS");
            continue;
        }
}
}
```

The error code I am getting is:

> error[E0599]: no method named `end` found for tuple `(usize, usize)` in the current scope

I am very new to rust and think it might be a simple fix, but cannot seem to figure it out.

Comment: Could you tell us what you are trying to do? What this `end` method is supposed to be?

Comment: Also your code is **terribly** inefficient. Calling `count` walks whole iterator in every loop cycle. You should probably just write `for x in data.chars()`, or something like this.

Comment: And what even `data` is? It is not defined anywhere. This code won't even compile.

Comment: I suspect you want `pos.1` instead of `pos.end`…

Comment: On a higher level, I don't think trying to parse this language with regular expressions will make you happy. You could try [pest](https://pest-parser.github.io/) instead, which is a somewhat limited parser generator, but easy to get started with if you are used to regular expressions.

Comment: Here's an attempt of a [pest grammar to parse your language](https://gist.github.com/smarnach/f21db92fabad821d5e8463e32bd99c67). It's probably incomplete and buggy, but it should be enough to get you started.